# Why does `Dir[directory_path].empty?` return `false` all the time?

Tags: ruby, directory

`Dir[directory_path].empty?` returns `false` all the time. The behavior is the same whether or not I run `irb` as root:

```
$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 2 ndefontenay ndefontenay 4096 Aug 12 12:11 ./
drwxrwxrwx 4 ndefontenay ndefontenay 4096 Aug  5 11:45 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ndefontenay ndefontenay    8 Aug 12 12:11 test

$ irb
> Dir["/opt/purge_entitlement/in"].empty?
 => false 
> exit

$ sudo irb
> Dir["/opt/purge_entitlement/in"].empty?
=> false
```

If someone could shed some light on this problem, it would be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> Dir[].empty? returns false all the time

It should,because it always contains the parent directory `(..)`, and the directory itself `(.)`,that you didn't take care of.

Comment: oooh. Thanks. I thought it was smarter than that :p

Comment: It's pretty dumb to have a function "empty?" that is not truly telling you if it's empty, from a human point of view.
What is that function good for at this point?
Does everyone write their own definition of "empty?" all the time?

Comment: @ndefontenay you can do also this way `Dir["/opt/purge_entitlement/in"][2..-1].empty?`

Comment: Actually the answer above works :)
The key to understand this empty? function is that it does not test the directory but rather a list of files in the directory.
providing a path looking like this: "myfolder/is/here/*" is key for a successful use of Dir[].empty?

We are not really testing the directory but rather if we can detect a list of files WITHIN the directory.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question, but to avoid the problem of getting `.` and `..` in the list, use `Dir.glob` instead of `Dir.[]`. You will probably get `true` for this:

```
Dir.glob("/opt/purge_entitlement/in/*").empty?
```

Comment: Ah ok. So you provide a regex looking for files which will then avoid . and ..

That makes more sense!

Comment: No, it's not a regex though it uses wildcard.

Comment: actually it's regex. The wildcard is just a very simple regex expression. It's not always the case but for Dir[], it is:
Dir[/opt/purge_entitlement/in].empty?
SyntaxError: (irb):2: unknown regexp options - prg

Comment: It is not a regex. Your example in the comment does not work, as you can see from the error message.

Comment: Obvioulsy, I used it to show the error. The keyword is: regexp options. It just says that it does not understand my expression.

Comment: The error was raised at the parsing level. You haven't even got to see the level whether `Dir.glob` can take a regex. You are confusing the slash for directory delimiters and the slash for regex literal.

Comment: Got you. Thanks for your help  and the discussion.